# Trouble working with a one-dimensional Java array with unspecified number of elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have a one-dimensional Java array:

```
    //Array with the thread of each client
    private Client_Procesor_Thread Client_Thread_List[];
```

When I want to use it, I do this:

```
    Client_Thread_List[Next_Client] = new Client_Procesor_Thread();
```

You may notice that, before creating the thread, I have to create the array like this:

```
    Client_Thread_List = new Client_Procesor_Thread[15];
```

However, I can't create the array, because I don't know how many threads I will have. This is a server, and I don't know how many clients I will have.

I know in other languages like Visual Basic.NET I can create an array of 15 elements for example, and after this, resize it to a larger one without losing the stored elements if I need to.

¿How would I proceed in Java?

Thanks for all,
Btc

Comment: you should use ArrayList

Comment: use a dynamic list, such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Your problem is with threads to begin with -- what if you expressed your problem with this angle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a kind of *growing array, use an `ArrayList`

Comment: This should be a comment please!!

Comment: This seems like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @RDC: I know it's a very short answer, but I think t answers the question.

Comment: Oops.. it was my mistake,@MrSmith42 Thank you for help +1

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<Client_Thread> client_Thread_List = new LinkedList<Client_Thread>();
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
example http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse341/06au/java/LinkedListExample.java

Comment: I did this just trying while debuging, because i didn't see your answer. Thanks anyway!